# Expectation associated with group of numbers

Tags: probability

What is the expectation of the number of numbers in an arrangement from 1-5 that would be higher than the ones next to it? I apologize for the structure of the sentence, I couldn't think of a better way to write it.

I tried to solve it as follows: We only care about 3,4 and 5. For 3, only 1 and 2 can be next to it, and they can be arranged in 2! ways and for 4, it would be 1, 2 and 3 in 3 * 2=6 ways and 5 similarly would be 4*3 = 12 ways. So, would the answer then be 12/120 = 0.1, as there are 120 possible arrangements. This seems very small?

**Edit**: The actual question is: "In all the arrangements of a circular ordering from 1 to 5 what is the expectation of the number(s) that are higher than the ones to both its right and left?" I interpreted this as the question I wrote above, but maybe I have misunderstood what is being asked here.

Thank You

Comment: I think you'll have to think harder. :-o  Can you, for example, list some example arrangements?  At this point, I can't tell what qualifies as a satisfactory arrangement, or indeed how many numbers are in a satisfactory arrangement.

Comment: @BrianTung I apologize. I have added the original question as an Edit. I didn't think the original question made much sense so I tried to give my interpretation of it.

Comment: Hmm.  Well, your statement left out that the arrangement was circular, which is a big part of it.  But in the original statement, we have an ambiguity in the term "the expectation of the number(s) that are higher than [its neighbors]."  Does that refer to the number of numbers that are higher than their neighbors, or to the expected *value* of a number that is higher than its neighbors?  You evidently have interpreted that as the former, but it's not clear to me what is intended here.

Comment: Also, no need to apologize! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

- $1$ and $2$ are *never* greater than both of their neighbors.
- $5$ is *always* greater than both of its neighbors.
- $3$ is greater than both of its neighbors only if it is between $1$ and $2$.

  - There are $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ ways to choose two positions for the $1$ and $2$ (relative to the $3$), so this happens in $5!/6 = 20$ of the arrangements.  (In this and what follows, we count rotations of the same arrangement as distinct.)
- $4$ is greater than both of its neighbors unless it is next to $5$.

  - Relative to the $5$, two of the four possible placements of the $4$ satisfy this conditions, so this happens in $5!/2 = 60$ of the arrangements.
- If $3$ is between $1$ and $2$, then $4$ is next to $5$, so it is not possible for both $3$ and $4$ to be greater than both of their neighbors.
- It is possible, however, for them both to *not* be greater than both of their neighbors, when $4$ is next to $5$, and $3$ is not between $1$ and $2$.

  - Up to rotation and reflection, there are only four possible arrangements: $12345, 21345, 31245, 32145$.  There are $5 \times 2 = 10$ different rotations and/or reflections of each of these four arrangements, so $40$ arrangements in all.

Thus, out of the $120$ arrangements, $20$ have the $3$ and the $5$ in qualifying positions, $60$ have the $4$ and the $5$ in qualifying positions, and $40$ have only the $5$ in a qualifying position.  With that, you have, hopefully, enough information to answer whatever interpretation of the question is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Could you please explain how you got $5!/6$ for the number of arrangements of 3? I see where the 6 is coming from, and the 5!, but I dont understand why $5!/6$ gives the number of arrangements. Also, if I was looking for the answer for my interpretation of the question, then wouldn't the answer be $(20+60+40)/120 = 1$?

Comment: No. The $1$ and $2$ are never valid, the $5$ is always valid, and $(60+20)120 = 2/3$ of the time, either the $3$ or the $4$ (but never both) is valid. Thus the answer is $5/3$. As for your first question: There are $6$ possible pairs of locations for the $1$ and $2$, each of which is equally likely, and only one of which is valid. Therefore only $5!/6 = 20$ positions make the $3$ valid.

Comment: I see. Thanks again. My last question is, why is only of the 6 possible pairs valid?

Comment: You arrange the positions in a circle.  The $3$ is at the top, and we label the other positions A, B, C, and D, going clockwise.  We must choose two positions for the $1$ and the $2$, which may be AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, or CD.  (Once a pair of positions are chosen, the $1$ may go into either of the two positions, and the $2$ goes in the other.)  Only AD is a valid pair; the other five pairs do not allow $3$ to be greater than its neighbors.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I have a further question though. Isn't there 3 out of 4 ways such that 4 would be greater than its neighbours? I'm unable to determine which are the 2 particular cases when it is greater.

Comment: The $4$ is not accounted for by looking at both of its neighbors; we account for it by checking to see only if the $5$ is next to it.  The $4$ is greater than its neighbors if and only if the $5$ is *not* next to it.  That happens when the $5$ is in one of the two spots away from the $4$, so there are $5!/2 = 60$ such positions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ X_i  $ be the random variable that is equal to $ 1 $ if the element $ i $ is greater than both its neighbours and $ 0 $ otherwise. We want to find

$$ E[X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5] $$

Due to linearity of expectation, we can decompose the equation above to find $E[X_i]$ individually for each $ i$.

1. For $ i = 1 $, the condition is never satisfied and therefore $ X_1 
       $ never equals $ 1 $. Thus $ E[X_1] = 0 $.
2. The same is true for $ i = 2$. Therefore, $E[X_2] = 0 $.
3. For $ i = 3
           $, $ X_3 = 1 $ with some probability. With some calculations, you
       get this value as $ \dfrac{1}{6}. $ Therefore, $ E[X_3] = 1 \cdot
           \dfrac{1}{6} + 0 \cdot \dfrac{5}{6} = \dfrac{1}{6}.$
4. For $ i = 4 $, the probability that $X_4 = 1$ is $\dfrac{1}{2}.$
   Therefore,  $ E[X_4] = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1  + \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 0
       = \dfrac{1}{2}.$
5. For $ i = 5 $, the condition is always true and hence $E[X_5] = 1$

Therefore, summing up, we get $$ 0 + 0 + \dfrac{1}{6} + \dfrac{1}{2} + 1 = \dfrac{10}{6} = \boxed{1.66} $$